# Linq statement to select rows from db and display as list in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to select all rows from a table with a status as closed, and then I need to display results in a list in a asp.net mvc view.

What should I place in the cshtml first line?

```
 @model HelpDesk.Domain.Entities.Ticket
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Help Desk | Admin Console";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.selectedSub = 0;
    }
```

How about here.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
}
```

Here is the method.

```
public Tickets GetTicketByStatus(string status)
    {
        return context.dbentity.Where()........
    }
```

Here is the model

```
public class Ticket
    {
        public int CaseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UFirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ULastName { get; set; }
        //public string UDisplayName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UDep_Location { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UEmailAddress { get; set; }
        //public string UComputerName { get; set; }
        //public string UIPAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ProbCat { get; set; }
        //public string IniDateTime { get; set; }
        //public string UpdateProbDetails { get; set; }
        //public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public string InitiatedBy_tech { get; set; }
        public string AssignedBy { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TechAssigned { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string ProbDetails { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TicketStatus { get; set; }
        public string TicketSource { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: There are tons of examples online about this. Check out [http://www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc). It has lots of tutorials about getting data from databases and displaying in your MVC web site.

Comment: Could you post the code of your Entity?!

Comment: posted code for entity